Package.json automatically creating default dependencies as "<project_name>": "file:"
I'm working in Node.js Project.
Surprisingly, app package.json crating a dependencies, "<project_name>": "file:", as follows:

After delete that dependencies, it's automatically regenerating again & again.
Do you any idea why it's happening ? 
I'm using vscode as code Editor. Is that side effect of any VsCode extension ?
My node version is: "18.17.0"

I had the same problem in VS Code, and for me, it was caused by the Red Hat Dependency Analytics extension. I had to disable all extensions and re-enable them one by one to find the cause.
The issue has also been posted on GitHub, and it seems to be related to the current version 0.9.5.

great ... when Red Hat Dependency Analytics added in vscode extension. When uninstall it, issue is resolved. Thank you @user26886906 for sharing valuable information
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.fabric8-analytics

Thank you. An alternative workaround is to use Red Hat Dependency Analytics version 0.9.4 without auto update until this is resolved
